# How to convert this one-line script into a git alias

Tags: git

I've made various unsuccessful attempts to turn the following one-line script into a "proper" `git` alias:

```
#!/bin/zsh
git add -u "$@" | perl -lpe 's/^add(?=\s)/stage/'
```

E.g.

```
[alias]
    stage = !zsh -c 'git add -u "$@" | perl -lpe \'s/^add(?= )/stage/\''
```

...but

```
% git stage .
```

...fails with a `fatal: bad config file...` error.

Comment: Does it work if you don't try and force it into zsh?

Comment: @CollinGrady: I had different errors if I used `!sh -c` instead...  (BTW, the error I showed is independent of the shell used; it's a syntax error for the config file; but some of the other errors are had were downstream from the config file)